# call jQuery function

Tags: jquery, json

I want that diffrent events to call the same function. I read other post, from here, but I   want use this function just in one page.

The situation is something like this:

I have approx. 80 listbox(select) in a form, and I feed them throught a plugin, jCombo (jQuery&jSON&php). First I relate each select listbox (`.change()`) to a hidden field, because I want to store index on table (update method is made with php). The problem is when I reopen same record for modify(same php file), jCombo change all `<select lists>` and reinitialize to 0. So my my event `$("select#listbox").change({});` change, obviously, my hidden field value to 0.

Having this situation I find a simple solution (I start use jQuery&Ajax three days ago) to unrelate function from select lists and relete to $("#AddButton").onmouseup({...});.
So, I write for 80 hidden field:

```
if ($("select#listbox_n_").val() != 0) {
   $("#hidden_n_").val($("select#listbox_n_").attr('value'));
}
```

,where n=1...80.

But now I must repeat this for Update button so:

1. there is other method to address a function by name?
2. what is the best place (eg.procedure or something) to "store" function, because I want to execute them, only if it's call.

Comment: Please format your question so that the code is readable. Have a look at the box to the right or here: http://stackoverflow.com/markdown

Comment: Please write your words so that they make sense.

Comment: So confused. I'm less worried about code formatting than trying to understand the end goal. A nice high-level overview of what the problem is would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but leave the code. I just want to exemplify in quick mode. I just want to call same function on diffrent events. Maybe something like this is working!? $(function nume () {...}); and call it with nume() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're trying to do is call one function from multiple events? If so, all you need to do is write your function and reference it in your events. And as for placing the function, just place it outside of your document.ready (`$(function() {...});`).

Just to illustrate, here's something I happened to be writing when I read this question. This checks the length of a textarea field, and returns it. This is just plain and simple HTML/jQuery.

HTML:

```
<label for="message">Message: </label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="70"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
       $("#message").keyup(checkLength);
       $("#message").keydown(checkLength);
       });

function checkLength() {
    var maxlength = 255;
    var charlength = $(this).val().length;
    var returnstring = (charlength + " of " + maxlength + " characters used.");
}
```

As you can see, the function `checkLength()` is called twice, on both the keyup and keydown events from the textarea. Note that, like I said above, they are placed OUTSIDE of the document.ready function. It then returns a string that contains how many characters have been added, compared to the maximum amount. Last, but not least, note that the function is called WITHOUT (). This means that it is just a reference to the function, and it will only be called when that specific event is fired.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! one more issue.
`$(function() {
       $("#message").keyup(checkLength);
       $("#message").keydown(checkLength);
       });`
should be called from document.ready, no?
So the question is why should I call through `$(function (){...});` method instead directly call `$("#message").keyup(checkLength);`

Comment: @drLeo The document.ready is merely stating that, when a character is put into the `#message`, the function will be executed. When the page is loaded, it does not actually call the function. This because I'm referencing the function, notice I say `.keyup(checkLength)`, and NOT `.keyup(checkLength())`.